# Scaling DC Voltage [0V-6.5V] to [0V to 10V]

Tags: dc

I have an input DC signal voltage 0V to 6.5V that need to be scale up to DC voltage 0V to 10V.
Any advise what type of circuit that I should use?.

Comment: How about an opamp with approx. 1.5 times amplification? The setup depends on your signal source and what it is connected to.

Comment: Is this a signal or are you trying to provide 10V power from 6.5V?  What power supplies do you have available?

Comment: Hi Olin Lathrop this only a for signal application.

Answer (score 7):

An amplifier, with a gain of 1.53 (10/6.5) you can make this using an op-amp IC and a few resistors.

There is a tutorial on using op-amps [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_3.html).

The circuit you need would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8yOFd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This site likes to be standalone and independent as possible. Please consider adding a circuit diagram that shows an opamp design that does what the OP needs.

Comment: How about using values that are actually available in the shop? When looking at E24 values 30 and 56 are closest (0.18%, which is much better than the tolerance of the components which is usually 1 or 2%). When looking at regular E12 resistors 12/22 or 18/33 are closest (both at 0.46% error for components with 5% tolerance).

Comment: 5.3k can be made from 5.1k and 2 100R values in series.

Comment: Yeah, but nobody does that in anything resembling production. Insertion cost, board space etc.

Comment: Agreed but using preferred values would not have improved the clarity of the answer

Comment: The signal 0V to 6.5 V after scaling up to 0V to 10V , the output will be transmitted to a computer. The output  used as scale to represent a a value by a computer program. The accuracy is 0.001 V