# Making a simple (but useful) oscilloscope using an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, frequency, oscilloscope, voltage-divider, hardware

I'm a first-year EE student who also has an interest in CS.  In order to boost my knowledge in both fields I decided to make a project which requires the use of my skills in both fields.

It came to my mind that I can make a simple but accurate oscilloscope using the volt-meter of Arduino Uno R3 and then plotting the data on my laptop using Python or Matlab. After doing some research I found out that I have two big problems.

First: The Arduino Uno has a 5 V limitation (or 1.1 V if metering in milivolt is required) when it comes to probing the voltage, so I had to find a way to scale voltage. After searching I found two ways to do so but I have difficulty choosing between them. [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353008/scaling-dc-voltage-0v-3-3v-to-0v-5v) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider)

so the question here is: **which one of these ways should I choose? and why?**

Second: According to my search, in higher frequencies the Arduino will lose its accuracy so I have to find a way to divide or scale the frequency too. I have found [this](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/test-methods/oscilloscope/scope-probes.php) method but I'm not sure that it will help or not.

and in this part I'm mainly asking: **Is there a way to lower the frequency in order for it to be simply measurable? or should I use a different approach?**

Any help with any of the mentioned problems is very much welcome. Since I'm a first-year I may have difficulty understanding some higher level concepts.

Comment: Hi, the post does not really ask any questions to answer. Please add some specific questions about the subject you have.

Comment: "scaling the frequency" assumes that there is only one frequency. That is not the case, there are just random voltages with a time stamp.

Comment: 1. Suggest using higher performance Arduino based on ARM chips.  It will be both a faster clock, and also 32-bit, in addition to probably better analog to digital converters.  2. FPGA's may give you better performance and still meet your goal of challenging hardware and software projects. They have FPGA platforms similar to Arduino, open source, ready-made.   3. Suggest you make some of the projects that already do this out there first before trying to tackle such an ambitious project. Unless you truly are infinite, of course. ;-}

Answer (score 0):

First: you need some time a divider (voltage too high) or an amplifier (voltage too low). A mix of the two is thus interesting.

Second: don't forget that it takes some time for the Arduino to convert a voltage sample (~ 100 us). Samples should be taken with the help of a timer under interrupt.
Use eventually some software to help (something as "ticker", or #include <TimerOne.h>).

Answer (score 0):

You've got more problems than you realize.  You've named two, and I'll add another two that you'll have to address.

1. Voltage limits.

You will have to scale large voltages down to fit the full scale range of the Arduino. That either 0-1.1V, or 0-5V.  You can use resistor dividers  (passive) or a circuit with selectable gain using an operational amplifier.

2. Sampling rate.

The typical Arduino software is limited to about ten thousand samples per second.  Because of the [Nyquist limit,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) you can only correctly sample signals up to about 5kHz.  You will have to filter out everything above 5kHz.  If you go around the Arduino libraries and access the ADC directly, I have read that the Uno can sample up to one million samples per second.  That would get you a maximum signal frequency of 500kHz.

3. Bandwidth of the analog section.

Regardless of what sampling rate you use, your analog circuit will have to be capable of handling the signal bandwidth.  Easy enough at 8kHz, somewhat more difficult at 1Mhz.

4. Serial communications bandwidth.

You want to transmit the data to a PC to be displayed.  The Arduino has a limit of 1 million bits per second over the USB/UART converter.  The Arduino has a 10bit ADC, so each value is 10 bits long.  You can (probably) send 10kHz data nearly in real time to the PC.  At 1MHz, you can forget it.  You would need to send data at 10 million bits per second over the UDB/UART converter - but it can only do 1 million bits per second.  You could try storing the data on the Uno and transmitting it later, but the Uno only has a couple of kilobytesof RAM.  That's not even one second at 10kHz.

Whatever you make with the Uno will be a toy.  Accept its limits, and use them to learn about bandwidth and sampling and how to design analog circuits.  Don't expect it to be a workable tool.  Expect it to be a learning tool, then learn what it teaches you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had no idea about the problems that you mentioned. You didnt mention anything about the frequency scaler (and wether I should even bother using that). And also by "the typical arduino software"  do you mean the software we install on pc for coding arduino or the software of the arduino itself?

Comment: There ain't no such beast as a "frequency scaler."  You can bandpass filter your signal then downsample it..

Comment: The "Arduino software" is the development environment as well as the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

First: method n°1, namely a "non inverting amplifier" is only capable of amplifying a signal, not attenuating it. Method n°2 draws current from whatever you're measuring, so depending on how much current already flows in the circuit you're measuring, you may alter it. To avoid this, you have to insert what we call a buffer between whatever you're measuring and your voltage divider. This should be enough for a very basic coarse input stage.

Second: Oscilloscope probes don't change the frequency of the input signal. X1 and X10 are voltage attenuations, not frequency, and the filter trimmer is only to trim high frequency performance. So don't tear any down, they're expensive and valuable for your real scope. Bear in mind that even if you find a simple way of scaling frequency, you WILL have to trade off latency. You can't compress or stretch time after all. What you CAN do is change what are called the "prescaler" settings of the ADC to speed the conversion up by trading off some accuracy.

You may in fact hit your next bottleneck which is the serial transmission to your computer, at the max serial baudrate. Either choose to do single shots and post-process the results after a "long" transmission, or there again make some new compromises. You may decide to use a more powerful Arduino-compatible board and hook up a screen + controls to do all the processing on board in real time.